# Windows 8 SDK Libraries Location

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-8

I've installed the windows 8 SDK in order to use the unofficial OpenGL SDK. There are a few dependencies needed to use the unofficial SDK, namely opengl32.lib, gdi32.lib, user32.lib, glu32.lib, and winmm.lib. However after installing the windows 8 sdk I could not find them in the instalation directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A) where they were located in the previous version of the windows SDK for windows 7. How would I get these libraries? Did I install the windows 8 SDK wrong? Or am I misunderstanding how to obtain these libraries?

Comment: My SDK installation sounds like yours.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A only has bin and Bootstrapper folders.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A has the bin/include folders needed to build.  Maybe this is by design?

Comment: I'm fairly sure they come with your compiler. Or at least, they come with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows 8 SDK was heavily reorganized from previous versions.  Inspired by the very different WinRT api and the added support for ARM processors.  The new home directory is "Windows Kits", the files you are looking for are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x86